Seeking Github Insights Tool Similar to Gitlights Analytics for Monitoring Team Activity
I'm managing a growing development team, and I need an effective way to monitor our GitHub repository's activity. Specifically, I'm looking to:

Insights of commits and pull requests per developer.
Generate weekly reports to review team productivity.
Identify trends or bottlenecks in our development process.

I've considered Gitlights Analytics, which seems to offer the features I need. However, due to budget constraints, I'm looking for a free alternative that provides similar functionality.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252624/title-case-or-sentence-case - hard to read titles like yours.
